# How can I export a VTK screenshot to a PDF or a vectorized image?

Tags: python, pdf, svg, vtk

I wrote a python script to render a VTK object and save its figure as PNG using the `vtkPNGWriter()` functions. Is there a way to save it as a PDF or a svg file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to export a PDF image of the render window using the function `vtk.vtkGL2PSExporter()`.
Here a working snippet of code:

```
pdfExporter = vtk.vtkGL2PSExporter()
pdfExporter.SetRenderWindow(render_window)


outputFilename = "file_name"

pdfExporter.SetFileFormatToPDF()  #save as pdf
pdfExporter.SetFilePrefix(outputFilename)
pdfExporter.Write()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vtk.vtkPDFExporter()` to get rendered data as pdf.

Comment: I've already tried the suggested method but it generates only an empty pdf file. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.